# Paypal IPN URL is giving error Failure: Missing Parameter

Tags: paypal, ipn

Hi we are using Drupal and civicrm 4.7.14.  Our client is having issues with renewing membership payments that go through on paypal (website payment standard - ID = PayPal_Standard) but are showing as Pending (incomplete) status in civicrm,
I looked at this article https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Standard+and+Recurring+Contributions
and noticed that the IPN and return URL was not set up in paypal.
But after setting up as per the guidance ( URL http://www.herdsa.org.au/civicrm/payment/ipn/2) and return URL www.hersda.org.au we received the following emails from Paypal 
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) messages. Messages sent to the following URL(s) are not being received:

http://www.herdsa.org.au

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information.

Once you or your service provider fix this problem, you or your service provider can resend the failed messages from the IPN History page. If this problem continues, PayPal may disable the IPN feature for your account.

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

Sincerely,

PayPal

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) messages. Messages sent to the following URL(s) are not being received:

http://www.herdsa.org.au/civicrm/payment/ipn/2

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information.

Once you or your service provider fix this problem, you or your service provider can resend the failed messages from the IPN History page. If this problem continues, PayPal may disable the IPN feature for your account.

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

Sincerely,

PayPal

When we checked the URL it says http://www.herdsa.org.au/civicrm/payment/ipn/2 says:

Failure: Missing Parameter

module

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please edit your question to indicate which version of PayPal you're using?  PayPal Standard, PayPal Pro?  Also please edit your question to indicate the payment processor ID?

Answer (score 1):

The "payment processor ID" is an integer, not a string - this may be your issue.  Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Payment Processor**.  Next to the PayPal Standard processor you're working on, click the **Edit** link.  You should get a new page with a URL that looks like this:

`http://dmaster.localhost/civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?action=update&id=5&reset=1`

Note the parameter near the end `&id=5`.  Whatever number is showing there (instead of "5") is your payment processor ID.  Change the "2" at the end of the pingback URL to match your payment processor ID.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes the id is 5 and I have updated the URL accordingly.  Hopefully this solves the issue.  Will keep you posted